# Find commands include files not in directory

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, find, hidden-files

there are only three files/subdirectories in my directory

```
root@acd95b24dde6:~# ls -l
total 1048
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1067355 Sep  6 12:57 apollo13.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       6 Sep 12 22:02 out.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     128 Sep 13 00:47 submission
```

however, when I call find, it returns me

```
root@acd95b24dde6:~# find -maxdepth 1 -type f -o -type d -not -perm -o=rw -not -path '*/\.*'
.
./.bash_history
./apollo13.txt
./out.txt
./submission
```

How do I get rid of the excess files?

Comment: Try `find * -maxdepth 0 -type f -o -type d -not -perm -o=rw`; The wild-card * will not show hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

There are in fact *four* files in the directory - it's just that `ls` omits hidden files ("dotfiles") by default, unless you add the `-a` or `-A` options. From `man ls`:

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

Ex.

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 apollo13.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 out.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 submission
```

whereas

```
$ ls -Al
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 apollo13.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 out.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Sep 13 07:29 submission
```

Unlike `ls`, the `find` command does not omit dot files or directories:

```
$ find . -type f -o -type d
.
./.bash_history
./apollo13.txt
./out.txt
./submission
```

So - why doesn't adding `-not -path '*/\.*'` not filter them out? There are two issues:

1. `*/\.*` only matches things like `./.bashrc`, not the current directory entry `.`
2. operator precedence rules (specifically, logical AND binds more strongly than OR) mean that

   ```
   find . -type f -o -type d -not -path '*/.*'
   ```

   is parsed as

   ```
   find . -type f -o \( -type d -not -path '*/.*' \)
   ```

   so that the `-not -path` test is only applied to directories - where it doesn't match, due to issue (1).

You can fix issue (1) by using a simple `-name` test in place of the `-path` test, and issue (2) using explicit grouping:

```
$ find . \( -type f -o -type d \) -not -name '.*'
./apollo13.txt
./out.txt
./submission
```